# Razor Syntax & Data Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, razor

I'm not sure if it's different when using Razor or not, and I can't find it in the MSDN Docs yet. Is it valid to do something like this?

```
string f;

foreach(string something in otherthing)
{
   f = something.Name;
}

<p>@f</p>
```

The part that relates to my question is `string f;` I know that you cannot declare a var without assigning to it at the same time, but what about String's? And where abouts would I find this type of info?

And why do all the websites (MSDN, MANY tutorials online) always seem to use var instead of string? Is it pure laziness? Is there a real point in using it (instead of)?

The reason I ask why they use var instead of String/string is because in cases where the value clearly is a String, they still use a var. Is it easier to convert vars to another type?

Answer (score 0):

You may declare a `string` without assingning it to anything. You cannot do this with  `var`s because C# must know the type of a var when it is declared, because C# is a statically typed language.

When the compiler sees `var s = "string"`, it sees that what is declared is a string and interprets that `var` as a string.

If the type can easily be inferred, it is more concise and sometimes more readable to declare a variable using `var` instead of an explicit type, such as `string`.

Comment: I always declare my variables strongly typed, except in the instance when I'm doing a LINQ query i'll use `var`.

Comment: @Nick, as is your right, but completely subjective.  *Many* people disagree.

Comment: @Kirk, It's funny you emphasize many. I've never seen one tutorial or piece of code where someone has done this. I'm not saying they aren't out there, but I think it's safe to assume that declaring your variable type is best practice.

Comment: @Nick, it wasn't possible to do before C# 4.0, so that obviously eliminates an enormous quantity of extant tutorials written before then from discussion.  As for its popularity, consider the top-voted answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633474/c-do-you-use-var

Comment: @Kirk, that would explain why I haven't seen it. I looked at the top rated answer, however I suggest you take a look at the top rated comment to that answer :) P.s. the last person to comment on that answer was not me.

Comment: @Nick, I'm not saying you're way is *not* popular.  I'm saying that your suggesting that "many" people do *not* use it is demonstrably wrong.  And anyway, 77 upvotes compared to 18 for the comment hardly demonstrates an unpopular point of view.

Comment: @Nick, I haven't seen many examples of people using var's but when I do I believe it makes your code easier to read and more succinct. For example: `Dictionary<string, string> userInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();` versus `var userInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>()`. It reduces excess clutter and also makes it easier to change the type later on without having to change it in two places. It's hard to say which is 'best practice' seeing as one is popular in tutorials and the other isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Worth checking out Scott Gu's posts on the razor views as he covers most thing on there:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Also if you haven't seen it yet the ability to use dynamic types with Razor is pretty neat and can be used with things like the postal library

Interesting read: http://aboutcode.net/2010/11/17/going-postal-generating-email-with-aspnet-mvc-view-engines.html